# no main.css file generated from gulp-less dotnet core in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, gulp, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have been following these two tutorials for first adding [gulp.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/less-sass-fa) & configuring [package.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-gulp)

But when go to Task Runner Explorer and right click on `less` Task and run it. Nothing happens.

**./gulpfile.js**

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='less' Clean='clean' />
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    less = require("gulp-less");

var project = require('./project.json'); 

var paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/"
};

paths.js = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.js";
paths.minJs = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.min.js";
paths.css = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.css";
paths.minCss = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.min.css";
paths.concatJsDest = paths.webroot + "js/site.min.js";
paths.concatCssDest = paths.webroot + "css/site.min.css";

gulp.task("less", function () {
    return gulp.src('Styles/main.less')
      .pipe(less())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(project.webroot + '/css'));
});

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
      .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
      .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
      .pipe(cssmin())
      .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);
```

**./package.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^1.0.6",
    "gulp-ext-replace": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-less": " 3.0.2" 
  }
}
```

**./Sytles/main.less**

```
@base: #663333;
@background: spin(@base, 180);
@lighter: lighten(spin(@base, 5), 10%);
@lighter2: lighten(spin(@base, 10), 20%);
@darker: darken(spin(@base, -5), 10%);
@darker2: darken(spin(@base, -10), 20%);

body {
    background-color:@background;
}
.baseColor  {color:@base}
.bgLight    {color:@lighter}
.bgLight2   {color:@lighter2}
.bgDark     {color:@darker}
.bgDark2    {color:@darker2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your less task looks wrong. Should be something like:

```
gulp.task("less", function () {
    return gulp.src("./wwwroot/styles/less/**/*.less")
      .pipe(less())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(project.webroot + '/css'));
});
```

If you have aspnet core project all assets are located in `wwwroot`. In your example you're looking at `./Styles/....`, should be `./wwwroot/styles/{path-to-less-files}`.

Comment: it took the code from documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/less-sass-fa

Its ./Styles not in ./wwwroot/styles